# A request for all site users

Tags: discussion

this site isnt even one day old and there are two rooms in the chat.
This will just divide the public between the two rooms.Hope you understand what i mean.
So i request users from making unnecessary chat rooms cause this will be a problem because we are in the nascent stage of site and participation is all that matters. Thank you